# remove rows at certain intervals in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like following

```
 structure(list(c1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 
2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1), c2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("c1", "c2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = "data.frame")


   c1 c2
1   1  a
2   2  a
3   3  a
4   1  a
5   2  a
6   3  a
7   1  a
8   2  a
9   3  a
10  3  b
11  2  b
12  1  b
13  3  b
14  2  b
15  1  b
16  3  b
17  2  b
18  1  b
19  2  c
20  3  c
21  1  c
22  2  c
23  3  c
24  1  c
25  2  c
26  3  c
27  1  c
```

In the above data frame there are 3 groups of (1,2,3) for `a`, 3 groups of (3,2,1) for `b` and 3 groups of (2,3,1) for `c`. What I want to do is to keep say 2 groups only for each of `a`, `b` and `c`. Is there any one line solution for this?

The output will look like following

```
    c1 c2
1   1  a
2   2  a
3   3  a
4   1  a
5   2  a
6   3  a
7   3  b
8   2  b
9   1  b
10  3  b
11  2  b
12  1  b
13  2  c
14  3  c
15  1  c
16  2  c
17  3  c
18  1  c
```

**NOTE: The initial number of groups for each category of `c2` can be anything (which is 3 here) and can't be known in advance , so the solution has to be independent of this initial number of groups.**

Comment: First of all your data frame is not a data frame but a matrix. That changes things a lot when you want to do some subsetting etc.

Comment: @sabDem Please assume it to be a data frame.

Comment: I know who down voted my question. My question is clear enough, if one can't understand it, please atleast don't down vote it in frustration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option that uses *data.table*. Assume `df` to be your original data.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[sort(df[, .I[1:2], by = .(c1, c2)]$V1)]
```

The number of groups we want to keep is given by `1:2` (the first two).  So if you wanted more or less, you would change the 2 to however many groups you want to keep. The above code  gives

```
    c1 c2
 1:  1  a
 2:  2  a
 3:  3  a
 4:  1  a
 5:  2  a
 6:  3  a
 7:  3  b
 8:  2  b
 9:  1  b
10:  3  b
11:  2  b
12:  1  b
13:  2  c
14:  3  c
15:  1  c
16:  2  c
17:  3  c
18:  1  c
```

Comment: `V1` is the column added from the intermediate procedure `df[, .I[1:2], by = .(c1, c2)]`.  We are using it for the row subset.